# How to create an instance variable only once?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class with an `ArrayList` of pre-determined items, in this example fruits. In my code I have a constructor call a method that populates my list.

The problem is every time an instance of this class is instantiated, the list is repopulated. How can I create and populate the list once?

```
public class Test {    
    ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Test() {
        populate();
    }

    public void populate() {
        lst.add("Apple");
        lst.add("Banana");
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to adding the keyword static, you can also put a "final" there; doing that gives you the guarantee that the corresponding variable is assigned a value exactly one time.

Answer (score 4):

You could make it `static`, and use a [`static` initialization block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html). I would also prefer to program to the [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface, and I would use a diamond operator `<>`. Something like,

```
public class Test {
    private static List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();
    static {
        lst.add("Apple");
        lst.add("Banana");
    }
    public Test() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Or**, use [`Arrays.asList(T...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) and eliminate the initalization block like

```
public class Test {
    private static List<String> lst = Arrays.asList("Apple", "Banana");
    public Test() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use static with static block.

```
public class Test {

    static ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();

    static {
        populate();
    }

    public static  void populate() {
        lst.add("Apple");
        lst.add("Banana");
    }

}
```

It will call once while loading a class.

Answer (score 1):

you can create singleton class

```
public class MyClass{

   private static MyClass instance;

   private ArrayList<String> lst;

   private MyClass(){
      lst = new ArrayList<String>();
      lst.add("Apple");
      lst.add("Banana");
   }

   public static MyClass getInstance(){
      if(instance == null){
          instance = new MyClass();
      }

      return instance;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the singleton pattern
u get many simple informations form here:
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html

depending on this surce, i can try it once with your class:

```
public class TestClass {

    private static TestClass instance = null;

    ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();

    protected TestClass () {
        populate();
    }

    public static TestClass getInstance(){
        if(instance == null) 
            instance = new TestClass();

        return instance;
    }

    public void populate() {
        lst.add("Apple");
        lst.add("Banana");
    }
```

}

so if u want to create OR get the class, run the getInstance() method and not the constructor (u even cant run the constructor cause it is protected)
notice: i didnt test the code, but it looks fine, if there are any problems or further questions, i still can run it to fix them, just comment then or let me know if it works / solved your problem

Comment: looks like i needed to long ro write it xD